# I've setup NordVPN via OpenVPN config on my pfSense router, but it will not connect

Tags: networking, openvpn, pfsense

I've setup NordVPN via OpenVPN config on my pfSense router, but it will not connect. I followed this how-to doc exactly and (TMK) did not miss anything:

https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Router/1626958942/pfSense-2-5-Setup-with-NordVPN.htm

However, the VPN is in a "(pending)" state for both Local Address and Remote Host, 0 bytes sent/received, service is running. Here are the most recent logs:

```
Apr 30 13:54:08 openvpn 87041   [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Apr 30 13:54:08 openvpn 87041   SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Apr 30 13:54:08 openvpn 87041   Restart pause, 40 second(s)
Apr 30 13:54:48 openvpn 87041   NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Apr 30 13:54:48 openvpn 87041   Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Apr 30 13:54:48 openvpn 87041   Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Apr 30 13:54:48 openvpn 87041   TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]212.102.45.57:1194
Apr 30 13:54:48 openvpn 87041   Socket Buffers: R=[42080->42080] S=[57344->57344]
Apr 30 13:54:48 openvpn 87041   UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET]174.29.101.70:0
Apr 30 13:54:48 openvpn 87041   UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]212.102.45.57:1194
Apr 30 13:55:48 openvpn 87041   [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Apr 30 13:55:48 openvpn 87041   SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Apr 30 13:55:48 openvpn 87041   Restart pause, 80 second(s)
Apr 30 13:57:08 openvpn 87041   NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Apr 30 13:57:08 openvpn 87041   Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Apr 30 13:57:08 openvpn 87041   Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Apr 30 13:57:08 openvpn 87041   TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]212.102.45.57:1194
Apr 30 13:57:08 openvpn 87041   Socket Buffers: R=[42080->42080] S=[57344->57344]
Apr 30 13:57:08 openvpn 87041   UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET]174.29.101.70:0
Apr 30 13:57:08 openvpn 87041   UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]212.102.45.57:1194
Apr 30 13:58:08 openvpn 87041   [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Apr 30 13:58:08 openvpn 87041   SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Apr 30 13:58:08 openvpn 87041   Restart pause, 160 second(s)
Apr 30 14:00:48 openvpn 87041   NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Apr 30 14:00:48 openvpn 87041   Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Apr 30 14:00:48 openvpn 87041   Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Apr 30 14:00:48 openvpn 87041   TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]212.102.45.57:1194
Apr 30 14:00:48 openvpn 87041   Socket Buffers: R=[42080->42080] S=[57344->57344]
Apr 30 14:00:48 openvpn 87041   UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET]174.29.101.70:0
Apr 30 14:00:48 openvpn 87041   UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]212.102.45.57:1194
```

Comment: Maybe your ISP is blocking VPN services. Have you tried suggestions in https://nordvpn.com/blog/isp-tracking/ ?

Comment: Good point, thank you. I am able to use NordVPN on all my endpoints, so does that mean my ISP isn't blocking it...? I will check the link. :)

Comment: Try using TCP with the 443 port instead of 1194 as specified in the how-to-doc link you provided