# No vpn would work on my pc

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, vpn, openvpn

I have problem with VPN connection , literally no paid vpn would work on my pc , i've been trying all internet solutions with no help..

when connecting via my internet goes down then i get error no internet

and other vpns keep connecting but never successfully connect , must give me an error :/

if someone helped me here i will give him 2 kisses on the cheeks i've been trying to solve this issue for months

this is the logs from hma vpn if it might help anyone to understand what is the problem

```
[2021-05-01 04:54:30.072] [info   ] [open_vpn   ] [ 4780: 6936] TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]*****:190
[2021-05-01 04:54:30.073] [info   ] [open_vpn   ] [ 4780: 6936] Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
[2021-05-01 04:54:30.073] [info   ] [open_vpn   ] [ 4780: 6936] Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]******:190 [nonblock]
[2021-05-01 04:54:31.084] [info   ] [open_vpn   ] [ 4780: 6936] TCP connection established with [AF_INET]*****:190
[2021-05-01 04:54:31.084] [info   ] [open_vpn   ] [ 4780: 6936] TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
[2021-05-01 04:54:31.084] [info   ] [open_vpn   ] [ 4780: 6936] TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]*****:190
[2021-05-01 04:54:40.749] [info   ] [open_vpn   ] [ 4780: 6936] Server poll timeout, restarting
[2021-05-01 04:54:40.749] [info   ] [open_vpn   ] [ 4780: 6936] SIGUSR1[soft,server_poll] received, process restarting
[2021-05-01 04:54:40.749] [info   ] [open_vpn   ] [ 4780: 6936] All connections have been connect-retry-max (1) times unsuccessful, exiting
[2021-05-01 04:54:40.749] [info   ] [vpn        ] [ 4780: 6936] Disconnect request processed, shutdown event was set.
[2021-05-01 04:54:40.751] [error  ] [vpn        ] [ 4780: 6936] asw::vpn::VpnConnectionProvider::OnException
                                                                Exception: ReadFromVpnPipe failed: 
                                                                Code: 0x000dbbb1 (900017)
```

Comment: [This question seems strangely familiar](https://superuser.com/questions/1645843/ive-setup-nordvpn-via-openvpn-config-on-my-pfsense-router-but-it-will-not-conn)

Comment: I'm not sure we can help you without more information.  Do you know if you are behind carrier grade NAT, or if your country filters all international connections?  What protocols have you tried?   Specifically have you tried using a VPN client that works over TCP port 80 or 443 (most use UDP and VPN ports)

Comment: Maybe your ISP is blocking VPN services. Have you tried suggestions in https://nordvpn.com/blog/isp-tracking/ ?

Comment: Can you parameter the VPN to use ports 80?

Comment: Two kisses? Lolol, I think people would rather a digital tip to get a cup of coffee. Try checking canyouseeme.org, with port (190?) If you haven't changed to port number yet.